# Java: How to terminate the process created with ProcessBuilder("startx", "firefox")

Tags: java, linux, firefox, processbuilder

How do I terminate the process I created with `ProcessBuilder("startx", "firefox")`? `process.destroy()` and `process.destroyForcibly()` don't work.

I'm starting a firefox kiosk, but only once the rest of the Java application is up and running (so that I can keep quick boot times and not have to wait for X to start). Is there a better way to do this than "startx firefox"? Is there a way of passing something to x to get it to close.

I need to restart the software to be able to update it. Obviously I'd rather not have to reboot the machine just to update it.

Comment: why do you need `startx`? Can't you run firefox with `ProcessBuilder("firefox")` (or similar, according to: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-run-firefox-from-the-command-line/)

Comment: @GergelyToth I can if I'm already booted in to a window manager. But I'm sidestepping that for two reasons: 1) it's wasted boot time. 2) I don't want a desktop. I boot without any GUI, directly to console. Then once the application is up and running I want the GUI to boot, to do so I need to start the window manager and firefox.